# How should I mount a TV stand on a wall covered in drywall?

Tags: drywall, drywall-anchor

How should I mount a TV stand on a wall covered in drywall?  Should I [trenail](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treenail) it to the wall?

Comment: How heavy is the TV you will be putting on it? Drywall may not be strong enough to hold it without using the wall studs.

Comment: See also http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/943/how-much-weight-can-a-drywall-withstand and http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/1667/flat-panel-mount-on-metal-stud-wall

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I wouldn't hang my TV from the drywall. You really should put it in a stud.

Comment: +1 ... definitely should hit a stud ... even the flatscreen TV's are pretty weighty when it comes to drywall, it would probably eventually tear through the drywall.

Comment: Get an inexpensive stud finder or try using a knuckle or a small finish nail to find the studs.

Comment: Depending on weight of the TV, you'll want to use at the very least something like a #10 2" screw into the studs. Often the wall mounts will come with even bigger lag screws (with a hex head) and again, those go into the studs.

Comment: You MUST use a stud!!! End of story.