# Can I hang a 60 lbs TV on 1 inch drywall?

Tags: drywall

Can I use drywall screws with plastic contraption 3/8" diameter to put a TV on the drywall?

What is the load limit for 1 inch drywall and how many screws and how close apart they can be put to carry 60..65 lbs TV ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to mount a TV stand in drywall](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/2207/how-to-mount-a-tv-stand-in-drywall)

Comment: Also http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/1667/flat-panel-mount-on-metal-stud-wall

Comment: 1" drywall?? Most is 1/2" - is that what you meant, or is this two layers of 1/2"? Either way, drywall as a material is not suitable - you need to mount it into a stud.

Comment: Yes. It is 2 layers of 1/2". It could be because the location is next to train station, so sound can be absorbed better.

Comment: NO. Terrible idea. Mount it to studs. If you can't do that cut out a sections of drywall and screw some kind of backer board down to the studs, and mount the TV to that.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Never mount a TV to drywall. Find some studs and mount it there.

Answer (score -7):

I have a 50" plasma mounted on no studs.  I used 10 toggle bolts and it is rock solid.  I would not do this with an arm mount though, just a flat mount.

Comment: -1 for inferring just becasue your less than optimal mounting has not failed yet that it is good enough for someone else. Always mount heavy things on walls by going into the studs. If necessary to have mount points between studs then suface mount 2x thinkess material across the studs and attach that to the studs. In turn mount the beacket onto the added 2x material. Make sure the added material is not cheap junk like MDF, particle board or OSB.

Comment: Some of you people on here act like mounting a TV is a procedure that needs to follow city code.  The thing weighs around 60 pounds... There are houses you have probably been in that haven't ever been inspected properly and definitely not up to code.

Comment: @EvilElf The purpose of the site is to tech people the **proper way** to do things. One of the most useful code sections I've read is from the National Electrical Code (NEC) "***110.12 Mechanical Execution of Work.** Electrical equipment shall be installed in a neat and workmanlike manner.*".  This could/should be applied to all aspects of home improvement, otherwise we'll be creating more problems then we solve.

Comment: Dangerous advice. There are many inappropriate solutions to problems that may make do for a while, or maybe forever. But as Tester101 says, let's teach how to do it right (and there are often several right solutions, but not heavy loads in just plasterboard).

Answer (score -8):

Mollys and toggles are perfectly suitable for this use. 60 pounds is well within the rating of a single fastener and you should use at least four. I am not sure what those experts in other answer comments are talking about.

Down vote away boys.

Comment: A single fastener may be fine for 60 lbs if the drywall is in perfect condition.  Drywall is not structural, however, and it doesn't take a lot for drywall to go from being in perfect condition to being crumbly powder, at which point its more like .6 pounds of pressure needed to rip something out, not 60.

Comment: Don't forget tremors and earthquakes. A mild shaking could cause damage that would not have happened had the mount been secured to studs.

Comment: Or a little wetness.  Damp drywall is about as strong as tissue paper.  If water's getting into the walls, sure, you've got bigger issues, but if you're mounting valuables to the drywall then you've added yet one more issue - broken valuables.

Comment: @TimPost - And having 60lbs forcibly detach itself from the wall is a bad situation. Being able to hold 60lbs static load means nothing when your framing makes trapezoids and you get some upthrust. Sayonara to anything in the landing zone.

Comment: http://i-cdn.apartmenttherapy.com/uimages/unplggd/081408_sz_holeinwall.jpg

Comment: Special fasteners may be able to keep a heavy TV mounted to the drywall, but what's keeping the drywall mounted to the studs? Drywall screws are designed to support the weight of the drywall, and not much more.

Comment: And yet, it moves!